# Dell monitor height adjustment and setting

Tags: display

I know how to adjust the height of a Dell monitor by pusing down on the release lock button. But how do you set it at a given height? Once you set it at a given height, and place it upright it will fall back to its bottom because of the monitor weight.

How do I lock it at a given height?

Comment: Mine just moves when I move it and stays in place otherwise. I've never needed to press any button. What model?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : I am set up for a dual monitor from today, got a new 2318 and my secondary monitor is 2314. Would like to raise the 2314 to the level of 2318, which is about 1.5 cm lower now. Bothers me :)

Comment: Sounds to me like your new monitor is heavier than the stand can support.  If this is the default stand that came with it, it may have a bad spring (not able to support its own weight).  My aftermarket stand has adjustment screws to account for different monitor weights, so you might look for that.